# Joint cumulative distribution of two independent variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution

I am trying to calculate a joint cumulative distribution of two independent random variables. Specifically, let X and Y be independent random variables, and let A be a constant. I am trying to write Pr(X < A,X < Y) which is essentially Pr(X < min(A,Y)). Answer to one of the following would solve my problem:

1. min(A,Y) is not valid since Y is a random variable and A is a constant (consequently something like `p(X-min(A,Y))(0)` does not work). Is there an alternative for min which would work?
2. Simply, is there a way to combine `p(X-A)(0)` and `p(X-Y)(0)` into one expression?

A cumbersome way to do it might be using `integral`, going from the definition although not sure how to approach exactly. It sounds like an easy question but I am rather new in R. Any comments or directions for a resource is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, P(X < min(Y, A)) = P((X < Y, Y < A) or (X < A, A < Y)) = P(X < Y, Y < A) + P(X < A, A < Y).

Second term is simpler; it is P(X < A) P(A < Y) = P(X < A) (1 - P(Y <= A)) = cdf_X(A) (1 - cdf_Y(A)) (although if X or Y is discrete, you'll have to be careful with < versus <= ).

First term is P(X < Y | Y < A) P(Y < A) = P(X < Y | Y < A) cdf_Y(A). I think P(X < Y | Y < A) = integral(cdf_X(y) pdf_Y(y) for y from -infinity to A) but I could be mistaken, you'll want to check that.

If you can't figure out the integral algebraically and you must resort to numerical approximation, try a method designed specifically for infinite intervals, such as QAGI from QUADPACK. I think there is a version of QUADPACK in R but again I could be mistaken.

Comment: Okay, this is actually useful. Then, as far as I understood, there is no built-in R function for joint probabilities.

Comment: Re: "there is no built-in R function for joint probabilities." Yes, that's right. You have to figure out the algebra yourself.